# Generating JPA entities with IntelliJ without a persistence.xml or orm.xml

Tags: java, spring, jpa, intellij-idea

Is there a way to generate JPA entities with IntelliJ without a persistence.xml file?  Or basically have IntelliJ recognize a persistance unit from Java Config?  I have an existing (legacy) schema and the project is a rewrite, now using Java Config in Spring Boot.  Per the Spring Boot docs, the persistence unit will be created by code:

```
@Bean
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean customerEntityManagerFactory(
        EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder) {
    return builder
            .dataSource(dataSource())
            .packages(com.abc.DomainThing.class)
            .persistenceUnit("abc")
            .build();
}
```

Comment: I solved this by having a persistence.xml in the project and not really used by code or checked in.  It just makes the IDE happy and I can bind a datasource to it to get the DB schema help in JPA Entity classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this by having a persistence.xml in the project and not really used by code or checked in. It just makes the IDE happy and I can bind a datasource to it to get the DB schema help in JPA Entity classes.

Comment: Did you get the Intellij JPA console to work at all? It looks pretty broken to me with the same setup as you - there is a right-click menu to "Add data sources" and "New->Persistence Unit" but choosing the options doesn't do anything at all. Not even an error.

Comment: I am sorry, I didn't relply beore.  I used a different tool for SQL.  I just needed the 'red' bits around Java to be satisfied in the Java editor.